# FacebookGraph /userid/feed Always Returns Blank

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the feed of others using the facebook graph.

The documentation I am following is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/feed

When a user authenticates, the scope I am requesting is as follows:

```
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = array('email', 'publish_actions', 'manage_pages','user_friends', 'user_posts'); // Optional permissions

$url = $this -> redirect($helper->getLoginUrl('http://www.example.com/facebookauth' , $permissions));
```

My code is the following:

```
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook(array(
        'app_id' => {{app_id}},
        'app_secret' => {{app_secre,
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
        'default_access_token' => {{access_token}} // optional
    ));

    $response = $fb->get('/'. '576368973' .'/feed', {{access_token}});

    $edge = $response -> getGraphEdge();

    print_r($edge -> asArray());
```

The problem is the response always returns an empty. If I use /me/ it works, but another userid, even if we are friends, is blank. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your access token if it really contains the `user_posts` permission? And is the permission already approved via the Login Review process? If not, did you try to login with an admin/tester/developer user of your app?

Also, you should specify the fields you want to have returned from the feed:

```
/me/feed?fields=id,message
```

for example.

- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#reading

Comment: Yes,I got the following scopes back with the access token test: Scopes user_friends, user_posts, email, manage_pages, publish_actions, public_profile. And I also modified the query string to specify fields, still empy

Comment: I am also using a test app. I think there is an oversight somewhere in the docs.

Comment: And also a test user? I guess test users have no feed information available